# How to add two vectors and print the results, which is also a vector

Tags: c

I have 3 functions in this code. The first one `vector_add`, takes the sum of two vectors, *x* and *y*, and puts them into another vector *z*, all three of which are made of *N=3* elements (defined at the top). The second one `vector_print`, uses `printf` to loop through the elements in z to print the *i*-th elements as an array. And finally, the main function, defines my inputs. My goals is to have the output read: `z is 3 5 7`, i.e., the sum of *x* and *y*. But currently, it outputs the following:

```
3.0000005.0000007.000000
z is 10
```

Obviously, this is not what I desire. But at least (somehow), the 3, 5, and 7 are there!

Experts, please take a moment to look at my code and provide suggestions to receive the output I desire. I want to keep this code in the same general format, i.e., 3 separate functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

// vector length (fixed)

#define N (3)

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// vector_add
//
// returns the linear sum of the two vectors and puts them in another
// x: first vector
// y: second vector
// z: solution vector

double
vector_add(double x[N], double y[N], double z[N])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    z[i] += x[i] + y[i];
  }
  return *z;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// vector_print
//
// prints the elements of an N array

int
vector_print(double z[N])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    printf("%f", z[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------------------
// main
//
// test the vector_add() function

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  double x[N] = { 1., 2., 3. };
  double y[N] = { 2., 3., 4. };
  double z[N] = {0,0,0};
  vector_add(x, y, z);

  printf("z is %d", vector_print(z)); {
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want blanks between the numbers and no decimal places. Did you study the documentation for printf()? Did you consider using ints instead of floats?

Comment: ... and actually printing the wanted space characters?

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings, and mind them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is lots of nonsense in there. `vector_print` does not return anything so its return type should be `void`. Same for `vector_add`.

`vector_print` *prints* the value. The `{ }` brace block is nonsense, too. Try this:

```
printf("z is ")
vector_print(z);
printf("\n");
```

To add space after the components and cut decimals, use `"%g "`

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
printf("z is %d", vector_print(z));
```

*first* the arguments to `printf()` are evaluated, which leads to the execution of `vector_print(z)`, outputting `3.0000005.0000007.000000`.

Then, 10 is returned from `vector_print()` and effectively

```
printf("z is %d", 10);
```

is executed, producing the output you observe. The `10` is btw some random value, since your function does not return a value contrary to what it promises.

If you want your function `vector_print()` to return a string, you have several options. The easiest is probably to return a pointer to a static char array like this (untested code):

```
char *
vector_print(double z[N])
{
  static char buf[100];
  char *ptr = buf;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    ptr += snprintf(ptr, sizeof(buf)-(ptr-buf), "%f ", z[i]);
  }
  return ptr;
}
```

and then print it with

```
printf("z is %s\n", vector_print(z));
```

Then it should work as you expect.